# getting the max() of a data frame under certain conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, max

I have a rather large dataframe with 13 variables. Here is the first line just to give an idea:

```
prov_code nuts1 nuts1name nuts2 nuts2name prov_geoorder  prov_name NUTS_ID EDAD year ORDER graphs value          prov_geo
1. 15      1        NW       11  Galicia     1          La Corunna   ES111  11   1975   1    1      0.000000000   La Corunna
```

I would like to obtain the maximum for a certain set of variables according to a combination of variables `year` `ORDER` and `prov_code` (ie, f_all being my data.frame: `f_all[(f_all$year==1975)&(f_all$ORDER==1)&(f_all$prov_code=="1"),]` ). The goal is to repeat the operation in order to obtain a new data frame containing all the maximum values for each `year`, `ORDER`, `prov_code`.
Is there a simple and quick way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestion on the matter,

Comment: `aggregate(value~year+ORDER+prov_code,f_all,FUN=max)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way of doing this, for example the one @James mentions. I want to suggest using `plyr`:

```
library(ply)
ddply(f_all, .(year, ORDER, prov_code), summarise, mx_value = max(value))
```

Alternatively, if you have a lot of data, `data.table` provides similar functionality, but is much much faster in that case.